# Load a sparse data array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, jupyter, sparse-matrix

I have multiple files composed of sampled data, each file contains x,y coordinates and the value of the variable. How can I possibly load this data as a sparse array (or matrix) where each sample is located at its position in the array and there are empty cells in between?

e.g., [image]

Comment: Could you be more specific about how the data is organized in your files? Is it a comma separated list? Will two files ever overlap X,Y pairs, then what do you do with the value?
ex.
X,Y,Value
1,1,1
1,2,2
...

Comment: 1          5.00           5.00               1.1687

Comment: Sample number  X   Y Value

Comment: It will require two steps - loading into an array in the original format, and then creating a sparse matrix from that.  Are you familiar with `numpy`?  Have you read the `scipy.sparse` documentation?

Answer (score 2):

The inputs are a little unclear ( I think you've mixed up 0 based indexing a little), but you can probably coerce them into this form and get what you're after.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

row  = np.array([0, 1, 2, 1])
col  = np.array([0, 1, 1, 3])
data = np.array([1, 2, 0.5, 3])
coo_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(4, 4)).toarray()
```

```
array([[1. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 2. , 0. , 3. ],
       [0. , 0.5, 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ]])
```

See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.coo_matrix for more examples

Comment: Thanks, very helpful I got ur point, but it is not possible to have an empty cell ( since 0 is a value as well)